# Tweet a published content on twitter from Drupal 7

Tags: social-network

My goal is tweeting content from a Drupal site as soon as a node / content is posted on the Drupal 7 site.

I follow all the instruction from this post ["How to automatically tweet a published content on twitter from Drupal 7?"](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3530/how-to-automatically-tweet-a-published-content-on-twitter-from-drupal-7) and did not work. What they recommend is to use the [Twitter Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter), this module you need to created an app at Twitter to make authentic it. I created the app and I'm able to pull all the tweets from Twitter to my site. Also, I'm able to sign in with Twitter however, I'm not able to automatic post a tweet after a node its created.

I can see the Twitter tab on my content type before I create a node. After I created the node a message said "Successfully posted to Twitter" but on twitter I cant see anything.  Can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this ? Or do I'm missing something ?

Comment: According to the module page you need to use Rules to post content. Have a look at the Rules module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created the Twitter app with the correct permissions? By default apps are only created with read-only permissions

Comment: Yes I change to read and write and still not working

Comment: Are there any related messages in Watchdog or the error log?